# CakePHP not loading associated properties with model on production server

Tags: cakephp, associations, models

This is a weird one.

I have a local server on which I develop apps. A product review app I developed works flawlessly on it, and utilizes Cake's associative modeling ($hasMany, $belongsTo, et. al.).

After pushing this app up to a production server, it fails. Gives me an error message:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: AppModel::$Product [APP/controllers/reviews_controller.php, line 46]

ReviewsController::home() - APP/controllers/reviews_controller.php, line 46
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83
```

I've `debug()`'d `$this` and it shows, plain as day, that, while the local server is loading the associated models, the production server is not. The databases are mirror duplicates (literally, the production server was imported from the dev db), and I can manually load models, which tells me it's connecting to the DB just fine.

What on Earth is going on?

**UPDATE**

The sql query from the production server is this:

```
SELECT `Review`.`id`, `Review`.`title`, `Review`.`product_id`, `Review`.`score`, `Review`.`submitted`, `Review`.`reviewed`, `Review`.`right`, `Review`.`wrong`, `Review`.`user_id`, `Review`.`goals` 
FROM `reviews` 
AS `Review` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Review`.`submitted` desc LIMIT 10
```

The sql query from the dev server is this:

```
SELECT `Review`.`id`, `Review`.`title`, `Review`.`product_id`, `Review`.`score`, `Review`.`submitted`, `Review`.`reviewed`, `Review`.`right`, `Review`.`wrong`, `Review`.`user_id`, `Review`.`goals`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`name` 
FROM `reviews` 
AS `Review` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`Review`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `products` AS `Product` ON (`Review`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Review`.`submitted` desc LIMIT 10
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's some of the code the errors point to:

```
$title = $this->Review->Product->find( 'first', array( 'fields' => array( 'Product.name' ), 'conditions' => array( 'Product.id' => $filter ) ) );
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
<?php
class Review extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Review';
var $displayField = 'title';

//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )       
);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache (i.e. tmp folder)?

Comment: If it's happening in one place and not the other it sounds like something is going wrong in deployment. I don't know of a reason that Cake would ignore an association.

Comment: Well if I could at least figure out where to start hunting down that problem, it'd make it easier to figure out which file is apparently failing.

Comment: Can you put up the code where the Product Model is called?

Comment: how did you define the relationships in Review model? It seems cake is ignoring all relationship of that model. Can you test if it happens with other models?

Comment: @Anh Pham: Updated question with Review model code.

Comment: does the file which seems to throw the error has proper access rights on the production server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem, and for me it was due to a missing field in one of the database tables. I'd triple-check to make sure both DB's are exactly the same (although you said they were...): feel free to use this 7-year-old app to check them :D http://www.mysqldiff.org/

Other people with this issue talked about filename issues and that all files should be lowercased, so that may be something to check as well...

Comment: I'll check this and make sure, but I'm fairly certain everything's kosher in that regard.

Comment: Did a diff, and there wasn't any difference :\ I'm at nearly a total loss with this one. It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: As it turns out, the FTP client I was using to move files had failed in overwriting initial caps model names to the lowercase ones I tried to test out per your second solution. The models after fixing it so they were completely lowercased worked perfectly. What an idiotic waste of time on my part.

Comment: I had similar issues when developing on Windows and deploying on Unix,really annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Actually - from a quick glance it might be worth using [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) to make sure your data calls are consistent.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of adding containable (but I would urge you to do so - it is one my favourite features of cakephp), you may want to set [recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive) in your find() call just to make sure the associated models are loaded.

Comment: How would this change between the dev environment and the production environment?

Comment: It shouldn't - but provided you have recursive set to 1 or 2 / the user + product model contained, and it still doesn't fetch the associated model data then you know the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a way of looking at the files on the server without going through ftp? I had a problem similar to this where the timestamps were messed up on the files and the server would not update the file. I had to delete the files, and then re upload them. You may have already tried this but I just thought I would suggest the possibility. Maybe some of those files are outdated on the server.

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I actually use SSH for most server ops, so all files are apparently there and up-to-date. Not to mention I've tried re-uploading the entire app 3 times already.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pastebin the Review model, Product model, AppModel, AppController, and the controller you are getting the error from.

The line:
Notice (8): Undefined property: AppModel::$Product [APP/controllers/reviews_controller.php, line 46]

Seems to indicate the Review Model is loading the AppModel and not the file you want it to. In that case the Review model won't have a Product association.

Comment: so why should it do so only on the production server and not on the development server?

Answer (score 0):

you can print the stacktrace out to see, here's some code I snatch from [php.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php#65433)

> ```
>  echo "<div>Stack<br /><table border='1'>";
> $aCallstack=debug_backtrace();
> echo "<thead><tr><th>file</th><th>line</th><th>function</th><th>args</th></tr></thead>";
> foreach($aCallstack as $aCall)
> {
>     if (!isset($aCall['file'])) $aCall['file'] = '[PHP Kernel]';
>     if (!isset($aCall['line'])) $aCall['line'] = '';
>     echo "<tr><td>{$aCall['file']}</td><td>{$aCall['line']}".
>         "</td><td>{$aCall['function']}</td><td>";
>         debug (($aCall['arg']));
>         echo "</td></tr>";
> }
> echo "</table></div>";
> die();
> ```

It's gonna be hard looking through all that though.